# Use a Rubber Band like the one displayed at Windows Desktop

Tags: qt, button, mouse, selection, drag

Is there a class that lets me use the same rubber band used on Windows Desktop? It's something like this:

[image]

If you see closely it's when you keep the mouse pressed and drag it over the Windows Desktop to select files.

What i need to do is to display some Buttons on that Widget and then if i want to select them all with the method i shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Your image/video didn't show up.</s>  EDIT: That is a very simple image... I thought it didn't show up at first.

Here is something in the direction of what you want:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrubberband.html#details

Comment: It should be showing, this is the link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/okGav.png I'll ook what you suggested.

Comment: If you're using the graphics view framework you can get this for free by using http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qgraphicsview.html#dragMode-prop